# Is “flatter than a mashed cat” a common phrase?

Tags: expressions

I became interested in the expression but can’t find out whether it has original or common forms. Why is it a cat?

> From the very first note she was horribly, hopelessly, irretrievably off key, and with each high note the problems were exaggerated. “Good God,” I would yell to myself, “you’re flatter than a mashed cat!” (*The Piano Shop on the Left Bank* by Thad Carhart)

Comment: he he. It's always a cat getting swung, mashed or precipitated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, it's not a popular phrase.

Why a cat?  Why not a possum, or a skunk?

When I read the metaphor, I immediately assumed it was a pun on the word "flat," and an allusion to [roadkill](http://www.wordnik.com/words/roadkill) (in other words, "*You're flatter than a run-over animal!*" - which doesn't read nearly as vivid as the original "*mashed cat*").

No way to tell for sure, I guess, unless Mr. Carhart frequents this forum.

Answer (score 7):

I have never heard this phrase before. I [compared it to another phrase regarding thickness](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flatter+than+a+mashed+cat%2C+flat+as+a+pancake&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), and the results show that it's not very popular as compared to *flat as a pancake*:
[image]

After that, I checked to see if it had *any* results:
[image]

Nope. I would say that it's safe to say that this is *not* a common phrase.

I also tried Googling things like "flatter than a mashed" (that one turned up four results) and "flatter than a mashed cat" (which turned up 2 results), so I can't find any related phrases.

Comment: I don't think you will find any related usages for *"flatter than"* collocated with any kind of *"cat"*. Apart from being "icky" in any literal usage I'm sure *"mashed cats"* are only metaphorically (and rarely, even at that) referenced in terms of their yowling, or belligerent attitude.

Comment: It's a play on the word *flat*- musically meaning to be off-key by having a pitch slightly below the true note's frequency.  I don't think Carhart intended the metaphor to compare the yowling aspect of the cat- only its "thinness"

Comment: @Jim: Feasibly. If Carhart wants to play with a mixture of metaphoric allusions, hes's not obliged to maintain any kind of chronological consistency. I at least can link *"cat"* to 50s jazz musicians, and *"mashed"* to current slang for "stoned, intoxicated", which might well cause the cat to play *"flat"* (below concert pitch). But only thanks to your comment there - I don't think I'd see that in a casual reading. It would be just the thoroughly rolled-out remains of a cat (fox?, rabbit?) on the road for me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: +1 for an intoxicated 50's jazz musician. It makes me laugh just tihnking about it.

Comment: @Jim: Absolutely - as I understand it, *mashed* usually means seriously under the influence of alcohol, whereas those jazz musos were more likely to be baked on cannabis (or addicted to opiates). But as I said in my answer, Carhart's a creative writer so he's got artistic license. Whatever - it's impossible to say how much of what we find in his text was consciously put there by him. *"The text is all"*, as we post-modernists say.

Answer (score 1):

To *scream/squall like a* [mashed cat](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22mashed%20cat%22&hl=en&biw=1290&bih=902&sa=X&ei=7lFpT9nUDomEhQeNvrW3Cg&ved=0CBwQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1900,cd_max:31/12/1982&tbm=bks#q=%22mashed%20cat%22&hl=en&tbas=0&tbm=bks&psj=1&ei=hVJpT_CSEYW2hAe34KDCCg&start=60&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=83eff03ccb2cc236&biw=1290&bih=902) is a pretty rare turn of phrase, but it accounts for most of the 75 instances of *"mashed cat"* in Google Books.

Of those 75, the only one I see making any reference to said cat being "flat" is OP's citation. Almost all the others refer to it being angry/howling. Perhaps Carhart chose "cat" because he'd heard *"mashed cat"* before, in that different context.

It makes little difference whether Carhart knew his usage was "non-standard" for the term - he's a creative writer. As @Jim says, *"flat"* here primarily means [off-key](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/off-key) *(singing at too low a pitch)*, but with the obvious allusion to a "squashed" cat being *physically flat* ([as a pancake](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+as+flat+as+a+pancake)).

Possibly he intended an oblique comparison between an off-key singer and a screaming/yowling *"mashed cat"*. It's also possible he's alluding to *"cats"* as jazz musicians from a generation or two ago, and to *"mashed"* in the modern sense of *stoned, intoxicated* (a musician in that state might well play flat). But we're getting into realms of Lit. Crit. there, beyond the scope of ELU.

Comment: Irrelevant?  Perhaps.  Then again, I suspect it was probably deliberate. One way to make the written word come alive is through original figurative language.  The author could have used the more familiar "_flatter than a pancake_", but that would have read much more, well, flat.  (I'm agreeing with you, save for the fact that I'd call it "brilliant" before I called it "irrelevant").

Comment: @J.R.: Definitely "irrelevant". Given how rare even the most "common" usage *("scream like a mashed cat)"* is, it stands to reason few readers would pick up on the allusion. I agree Carhart's usage is quite evocative, but to most readers it'll quite simply call to mind a long-dead, repeatedly driven-over, exceptionally flat bit of feline roadkill. The agonised howling of a not-quite-dead cat **hit** by a car just won't occur to them, whether Carhart knew of it or not.